# How can I create an Array of objects from arr array in javascript using spread operator? - Trying to fit all of the code on to one line

Tags: javascript

Need to create one object per objectid and create an array of contacts for that object.
I have done it without spread operator but wondering how this can be done using spread operator.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "objectid": 1,
    "userid": "1",
    "associationid": "123"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 1,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  },  
  {
    "objectid": 2,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  }
];
//My working code without using spread operator
let res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, {objectid, userid, associationid}) => {
    (acc[objectid] ??= {objectid, contacts : []}).contacts
      .push({isdelete: '1', contactid: userid, associationid});
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(res);

//Tried the following code using spread operator but not working
const res = arr.reduce((acc, {objectid,userid,associationid}) =>
  ({ ...acc, (acc[objectid] ??= {objectid, contacts : []}).contacts.push({isdelete: '1', contactid: userid, associationid}) }),
  {})
  
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `(acc[objectid] ??= …)` makes no sense inside an object literal

Comment: What reason do you have to _want_ to use `spread`? Are you just trying to fit all of the code on to one line?

Comment: Learning purpose and trying to fit all of the code on to one line.

Comment: @KarimAli The code that adds to the accumulator object already *is* all in one statement. And as you can see from the answers, it doesn't actually get any shorter.

Comment: @Bergi It can definitely get shorter with the comma operator (as shown in my answer).

Comment: @Unmitigated I mean it doesn't get shorter from using spread syntax (on the objects, or on the array, or both). Of course you can always make it shorter (and less readable) by minifying the code, getting rid of whitespace etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code I hope it answers your question

```js
const arr = [{
    "objectid": 1,
    "userid": "1",
    "associationid": "123"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 1,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 2,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  }
];

const res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, {
    objectid,
    userid,
    associationid
  }) => {
    acc[objectid] = {
      ...acc[objectid],
      objectid,
      contacts: [
        ...(acc[objectid]?.contacts ?? []),
        {
          isdelete: '1',
          contactid: userid,
          associationid
        },
      ],
    };
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mutate an array within an object while spreading the object at the same time, which is syntactically incorrect. I am using the spread operator to keep the previous contacts and add the new one.

```js
const arr = [{
    "objectid": 1,
    "userid": "1",
    "associationid": "123"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 1,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 2,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  }
];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, {
  objectid,
  userid,
  associationid
}) => {
  if (!acc[objectid]) {
    acc[objectid] = {
      objectid,
      contacts: []
    };
  }

  return {
    ...acc,
    [objectid]: {
      ...acc[objectid],
      contacts: [
        ...acc[objectid].contacts,
        {
          isdelete: '1',
          contactid: userid,
          associationid
        }
      ]
    }
  };
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) to always return the accumulator after modifying it.

```js
const arr=[{objectid:1,userid:"1",associationid:"123"},{objectid:1,userid:"2",associationid:"456"},{objectid:2,userid:"2",associationid:"456"}];
let res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, {objectid, userid, associationid}) => 
    ((acc[objectid] ??= {objectid, contacts : []}).contacts
      .push({isdelete: '1', contactid: userid, associationid}), acc), {})
);
console.log(res);
```